# Source of vanishing/exploding gradients in RNN

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, derivative

### Problem

I am trying to understand the source of vanishing/exploding gradients in vanilla RNN. The update rule of vanilla RNN is

$$
      \begin{aligned}
      &\mathbf{a}^{\left<t\right>}=\tanh(\mathbf{W}_ {aa}\mathbf{a}^{\left<t-1\right>}+\mathbf{W}_ {ax}\mathbf{x}^{\left< t\right>}+\mathbf{b}_ a)\\
      &\mathbf{y}^{\left<t\right>}=g(\mathbf{W}_ y\mathbf{a}^{\left<t\right>}+\mathbf{b}_ y)
      \end{aligned}
$$

To my understanding, only $\mathbf{W}_{aa}$ and $\mathbf{W}_y$ will cause the issues since they all require $\nabla_{\mathbf{a}^{\left< t\right>}}f$, where $\mathbf{a}^{\left<t\right>}$ is in turn dependent on previous steps, which result in multiplicative terms $(\mathbf{W}_{aa}^{T})^k$ and $(\mathbf{W}_{y}^{T})^k$ and thereby vanishing/exploding gradients. However, since $\nabla_{\mathbf{x}^{\left< t\right>}}f$ does not depend on previous steps. So $\mathbf{W}_{ax}$ **will not** cause the problem.

Is my understanding correct? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the gradient through $W_{ax}$ will stop there, and does not get propagated any further backwards in time. There is no gradient $dx_{t}/dx_{t-1}$ so there is no accumulated multiplicative terms. However, the gradient through $W_{aa}$ gets propagated through $da_{t}/da_{t-1}$ and will cause exploding/vanishing gradients through the accumulated multiplication terms.

Answer (score 1):

The vanishing and exploding gradients in any neural network, not just RNN. I think they are caused by the multiplication of the gradients across layers (chain rule). If you have a neural network that represents as (not exact):

$$f(x) = A(B(C(x)))$$

The derivative or gradient calculation would be:

$$
\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{dA}{dB}\frac{dB}{dC}\frac{dC}{dx}
$$

If the network has many layers, the multiplications add up, which causes either gradients vanishing or exploding, especially for RNN.

See here: https://medium.com/learn-love-ai/the-curious-case-of-the-vanishing-exploding-gradient-bf58ec6822eb